# like query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I want search data on key press which started with key which is enter textbox. For following I execute mysql query

> SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `colounm_name` LIKE 'w%'

When I give query

> $this->db->like('colounm_name',$data['feild_name']);

it's print

> SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `colounm_name` LIKE '%w%'

it's fetch all  data which has content w

please convert first query in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db->like('column', 'value', 'after');

Everything is in the docs [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)